# Pandas search and replace with dictionary

Tags: regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace some keywords in pandas dataframe using dictionary, the data in column is a filepath, it should replace the keyword in the dictionary if it exists in filepath.

```
title_rename = {'ABCD':'LWD','MSC':'MWD', 'MRI':'MD' ,'TRI':'TXD'}
all_files.replace({'Title':title_rename},inplace = True)

EX : ABCD - GHG - Recorded Mode - MRI.txt - it should replace to ABCD - GHG - Recorded Mode - MD.txt
```

if the title contains any of these keyword then it should replace and case insensitive. currently it replaces if its a exact match and does not search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas str:

`for k,v in title_rename.items():
     all_files.Title = all_files.Title.str.replace(k,v)`

Comment: its not a exact match, the string is like : ABCD - GHG - Recorded Mode - Measured Depth - Final it should replace to ABCD - GHG - Recorded Mode - MD - Final